# framework not correctly imported? Mach-O Linker on 'MultipeerConnectivity'

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, multipeer-connectivity

I erased the multipeerConnectivity framework, and moved it to trash, I thought it would just remove it from the xcode project, but since then, I have got error when I try to use it again:

I tried to copy it from a drag and drop in xcode, or by adding it via "add other framework" (xcode does not recognize the name in the search input), I created again the project from Apple from the .zip file, it worked one time, the first time it was launched, but now it is impossible to run the project :

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you deleted it entirely, instead of removing the reference, you have to add it back to the folder in Finder, it's not like adding images where you can 'copy items if needed' :

The easiest way is go to your trash and select the framework > right-click > put back

or to navigate directly to the frameworks folder :

Macintosh HD > System > Library > Frameworks

To ensure you place it in the right Frameworks folder (there are multiple) you can directly go to it by clicking on your Finder icon (new finder window) then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or Finder > Go > Go to Folder...

In the prompt box type in :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks
```

You'll automatically be taken there. Just put the framework back in that folder, close & restart Xcode and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks, I put it back in my User folder after I sent it to trash, so I cannot do put back, but i added it to the frameworks folder, switch off my computer and tried again, Xcode does not recognize it in "Link binary...", so I add it with "add other", I go to my framework folder, add it, and `@import MultipeerConnectivity` throws an error on the line.  (in a new project) I tried to add -ObjC as suggested by @ko100vd , the version is 8.1, but still no luck... any other idea?

Comment: @Paul  You added it to the 'System' framework folder? __NOT__ User framework folder correct? if it doesn't recognize it in link binary that means its still not in the Macintosh HD > System > Library > Frameworks folder

Comment: @Paul I've updated my answer for flexibility; and i'm hoping `@import` is a typo and you meant `#import <>`

Comment: Thanks, yes it is right there, I looked at the path in the Terminal, it shows the framework in the folder. But then in Xcode, typing "mul..." does nothing, the window of framework available is empty. I can find it if I click on "add other..." though, but then the same error as above. About the syntax, I tried both, @import was in the documentation, but both don't work. (it cannot find the module, even if I added it via "add other")

Comment: Hmm. If you added it to the folder but it still isn't auto populating means Xcode still doesn't think it's there. I'm stumped then.

Comment: I removed Xcode with a sudo command, then re-install it, and it works. Finally ;-) Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your frameworks in linker flags:

Build settings -> Other Linker Flags
Add new value there, try with
**-ObjC**

Or find a way to make your app 64bits if your developing under iOS 8.0 or higher this might solve your problem too :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's hard to make it work, nothing changes with this way or the answer from soulshined. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Hm.. you should research how your frameworks **link** with the foundation frameworks, and those links you your **Other Linkers Flag**. Also if you have implement two or more frameworks such as , Google Maps SDK and Facebook iOS SDK they can interfere between them self, its hard to find the problem it can be caused by many things, Clean the cache, clean the project restart XCode delete the debug folder ... it is iOS after all we must expect everything to work, i wish you good luck :)